# MySQL - Delete with IN Clause taking more time

Tags: mysql, innodb, delete

In MySQL 5.6 I have around 60 million rows. I wanted to remove rows based on Id. Here Id is the primary key.

One strange behavior I had today.

```
delete from tbl where id=1;
```

Its executed in milliseconds.

Then I did this.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE DELETE_ID (ID int);
Insert into DELETE_ID select id from (subery1(subquery2(subquery3)));
```

The DELETE_ID has around 150 ID.

```
Delete from tbl where id in (select id from DELETE_ID);
```

Its taking more than 30mins, but deleting a single row.

There were no locks or deadlock.

In innodb_trx the status was sometimes `fetching rows` sometimes `unlocking rows`.

Can anyone help me to understand why this is happening?

Comment: *WHERE .. IN* is slow in most cases. Use multi-table delete `delete tbl.* from tbl, DELETE_ID where tbl.id = DELETE_ID.id`.

Comment: Hi @Akina can you please help me to understand how this In clause made the process slow?

Comment: In general most RDBMS have terrible performance for IN clauses.  The optimizer may rewrite it to (or ID = 1 or ID =2 or ID =3 or ID =....).  Here's one link discussing it: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/03/25/mysql-in-query-performance/

Comment: @Akina - Make your Comment into an Answer; it is likely to be the best Answer.

Comment: @RickJames Done...

Comment: Marked as Answer. Thanks @Akina and RickJames

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WHERE .. IN` is slow in most cases.

Use [multi-table delete](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE tbl.* 
FROM tbl, DELETE_ID 
WHERE tbl.id = DELETE_ID.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete from tbl where  EXISTS (SELECT id FROM DELETE_ID                 WHERE tbl.id = DELETE_ID.id);

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site. Can you explain to the OP why his construction is slow and why this one should be faster? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance

Comment: I don't think that reference applies in that case.  _There_ it is talking about having to scan to see if it exists and stopping short ("semi-join").  _Here_ it is not the speed of the `EXISTS`, but the fact that it involves a 'correlated' subquery and will perform the `EXISTS` for each and every row in `tbl`.